# Share the session storage between website and Iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, session-storage

I have a web app written in vanilla JavaScript and inside it there is a Iframe. I want to access the data stored by the web app in session storage from Iframe and vice versa. The Iframe application written in ReactJS. How can i achieve this, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate with an Iframe.
in your case Iframe should listen for your message and responds with a copy of session storage.